# How to use CAN-Bus on an Intel Atom Q7 module with EG20T chipset on Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, linux-device-driver, can-bus

I want to use the CAN-Bus interface on an Intel Q7 module with the EG20T chipset. I got it to work on Windows but now i have to get it to work on Linux but I barely find any information.

I just need to know how I can read, write messages, start, stop and to set the baud-rate of the CAN-Bus.

So far I found this: http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/PCH_CAN.html
and some comments about can4linux and socketCan for shell usage.

But I actually need to know how to use it within a C or C++ programm.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like that driver is a SocketCan driver. Just compile and load the module, and then your device will look like a network interface.

http://www.brownhat.org/docs/socketcan/llcf-api.html

This link has information about how to send messages and such.
Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Look here for more information about socketcan and linux implementation:
[socketcan](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/can.txt)

Answer (score 1):

Modern Linux distributions provide SocketCAN drivers from stock. So there is no need to compile the driver yourself.

SocketCAN project provides utils for sending/receiving CAN frames and other related tasks. Please see this repository: https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils

There is also a central SocketCAN dedicated wiki: http://elinux.org/CAN_Bus